# How can I deserialize a Yaml object containing strings into a List<string>?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I created a Yaml with filenames, so I can make my program check if every file of the list exists. I haven"t done much with yaml yet, and the documentations don't really help me.

This is my Yaml (It's pretty small):

```
DLLs:
    - Filename1
    - Filename2
    - Filename3
```

At the moment, this is my code:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("./Libraries/DLLList.yml")))
{
    /*
     * List<string> allDllsList = deserialized yaml.getting all values of the "DLLs"-list
     */

    var deserializer = new Deserializer();

    var dlls = deserializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader)["DLLs"] as List<Object>;
    /*This gives me the Error "Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object] cannot be converted into "System.String""*/
    List<string> allDllsList = dlls.Cast<String>().ToList();
}
```

Can someone explain to me how I can get the values out of the Yaml file, and why it works in the way you do it?

Edit: Now it works, I used the wrong yaml, I had 2 versions

Comment: Did you try putting in a breakpoint, inspecting the return value from `deserializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader)` in the debugger, and seeing what's in there?

Comment: Then you use your watch window to see what's in there. See answer. Where did you get the `Values` idea from?

Comment: I meam, this is the Object in Visual Studio: https://ibb.co/WppGXH2

Comment: So you use the watch window to gather information about the object: Its type, its properties, the types and values of its properties. It's a `dynamic` reference to a Dictionary with keys and values. The keys are strings. The value for the "DLLs" key is `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take the return value from `deserializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader)` and inspect it in the debugger. It's a `Dictionary<String, Object>`, and it's got an entry named "DLLs" that contains a `List<Object>`. The objects in that list are all strings. There you go:

```
var dlls = deserializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader)["DLLs"] as List<Object>;

//  Use .Cast<String>() as shown if you want to throw an exception when there's something 
//  that does not belong there. If you're serious about validation though, that's a bit 
//  rough and ready. 
//  Use .OfType<String>() instead if you want to be permissive about additional stuff 
//  under that key.
List<string> allDllsList = dlls.Cast<String>().ToList();
```

Comment: Then I get this error:

Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]"  cannot be converted into "System.String"

Comment: Not in my compiler. Please paste the current version of your code into your question.

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn Thanks for the update. What YAML parser are you using, and have you confirmed that there's definitely no additional structure to the file? What you're seeing looks to me like there's an additional branch under "DLLs" in the YAML.

Comment: Yeah I had 2 files. One just had the values in ```DLLs``` and the older one had them in List inside that ```DLLs```. And I'm using the YamlDotNet Nuget

Comment: Awesome. Just as well I used `Cast<String>()`, in that case.

Comment: Yeah. I could have done it in Json, that's easier to deserialize for me, but Yaml looks much better for what I want to do

Comment: YAML's almost exactly what i always thought JSON should've been from the get-go. I've been meaning to learn it, and this question got me going, so thanks!

Comment: if Json wouldn't be so ugly (and unable to store comments) and xaml wouldn't be almost unreadable in large size, i'd use one of them

Comment: We'll get a mature, fully featured, non-silly text format for structured data a year or two after text formats for structured data become totally obsolete. I can't wait!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201332/discussion-between-dudewhowantstolearn-and-ed-plunkett).